# Generating Sequences with Irregular Patterns in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to generate a column that shows persistence throughout a field.  The field is sequential and numeric, but not conventionally increasing.  Essentially, it goes up by 7 (when it ends in 2) and then 3 (when it ends in 9) by each ID.  It's possible for an ID to miss one or more of the sequence, but then return to the same pattern.  The data looks like this:

```
ID      Col
1       0769
1       0772
1       0779
1       0782
1       0799
1       0802
1       0812
2       0769
2       0772
2       0779
3       0782
3       0799
3       0802
3       0812
```

What I'm trying to do is generate this:

```
ID      Col        Persistence
1       0769       1
1       0772       1  
1       0779       1
1       0782       1
1       0799       2
1       0802       2
1       0812       3
2       0769       1
2       0772       1
2       0779       1
3       0782       1
3       0799       2
3       0802       2
3       0812       3
```

Comment: So "Persistence" should increase by 1 whenever The "Col"-column fails to fit the pattern `...2,...9,...2,...9`? (Your natural language description doesn't read like that to me but that seems to be what your example implies.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make sure the jump is either 3 or 7, you can write a helper function to increment when a jump of a different size occurs

```
jumpchange <- function(x) c(0,cumsum(!diff(x) %in% c(3,7)))+1
```

Then you can apply this to each group most easily with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(persistence = jumpchange(Col))
```

Or you can use `transform/ave` with just base R

```
transform(dd, persistence=ave(Col, ID, FUN=jumpchange))
```

Comment: If you use `jumpchange <- function(x) cumsum(!(x - lag(x, fill = 0)) %in% c(3, 7))` you can avoid the `c(0, ` and `+1`. That also keeps it as an `int` instead of `double`

Comment: I needed the opposite of the !diff, but that worked when I removed the !.  Thanks!